# Merge tag [zprezto] into [prezto]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[zprezto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zprezto) (actually `~/.zprezto`) is where [prezto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prezto) is [installed](https://github.com/zsh-users/prezto#installation). It's not a different thing.

Can this tag be merged?

Comment: [zprezto] has 3 questions in about 2 years. Perhaps they can just be retagged?

Comment: can't you just retag those 3 (now 2)  questions and then wait for the tag cleanup script to run at 03:00 UTC to get rid of that tag?

Comment: Sure, didn't know that was the thing to do. Thanks.